# Waves: Get 15 mnemonic words from a hex seed

Tags: cryptocurrency, wavesplatform

Is there a way to get the 15 mnemonic words from a given hex seed?

Any method in the waves JS crypto library to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If by hex seed you mean byteEncoded or base58encoded seed, then yes:

```
const {libs} = require('@waves/waves-transactions')

// convert base58 string to bytes
const encoded = 'xrv7ffrv2A9g5pKSxt7gHGrPYJgRnsEMDyc4G7srbia6PhXYLDKVsDxnqsEqhAVbbko7N1tDyaSrWCZBoMyvdwaFNjWNPjKdcoZTKbKr2Vw9vu53Uf4dYpyWCyvfPbRskHfgt9q'
const bytes =  libs.crypto.base58decode(encoded)
// if string is hex encoded use this function instead
// const bytes libs.crypto.hexStringToByteArray(encoded)
const decoded = libs.marshall.parsePrimitives.P_STRING_FIXED(bytes.length)(bytes)

console.log(decoded)
```

Otherwise it is not, since hash function is irreversible